# How to get the value of $16\cot\theta$ from a half circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below represents the half of an apple pie. Assuming
> that each portion costs $16\cot\theta$ cents. How many people would
> have eaten if it was collected $3264$ cents?

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{148 kids}\\
2.&\textrm{136 kids}\\
3.&\textrm{124 kids}\\
4.&\textrm{156 kids}\\
\end{array}$

From the given expressions I could spot that:

$\triangle PCR$ is a right isosceles. Because $PR=CR$

The same holds for $\triangle CQR$ because $PR=RQ$ as $\triangle POQ$ is isosceles.

But that's where I'm stuck. The whole key in this problem is **how to get the PO in terms of what I've found?.**

Can someone help me here?.

Because if I'm able to get that result the number of kids can be found from:

$K=\frac{3264}{16\cot\theta}=\frac{204}{\cot\theta}$

But again, what should be done here?. Can someone help me please?.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$$|CR||RC'|=|MR||RN| \quad\to\quad u\cdot(u+2u\cot\theta)=2u\cdot2u \quad\to\quad\cot\theta=\frac32$$

Answer (score 1):

The radius of the pie is $CR+RO$.

Given $CR=MP=PR$, consider the right-angled triangle $\triangle MRO$,

$$\begin{align*}
MO &= \text{radius}\\
MO^2 &= RO^2 + MR^2\\
(PR+RO)^2 &= RO^2 + (2PR)^2\\
PR^2 + 2PR\cdot RO + RO^2 &= RO^2 + 4PR^2\\
2PR\cdot RO &= 3PR^2\\
\frac{RO}{PR} &= \frac{3}{2}\\
\cot\theta &= \frac 32
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let CR = $\frac12$MR = a and RO = b. Then, OM = a + b and the Pythagorean’s rule for MRO establishes $b^2+4a^2 =(a+b)^2$, yielding $\cot \theta = \frac ba =\frac32$ and the answer (2).